# GUI Tool using PowerShell to view .htm report in pane

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am new to PowerShell can anyone please help how to achieve this.

I am trying to build a GUI Tool which does the below.

1. It should fit to the screen
2. I create a button and once I click on the button the resultant output which is in (.html) page should fit in the pane and should be reflecting in the right hand side pane in the same GUI Tool.

So far I have tried the below code.

```
#Create Form Object
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,300)
$Form.Text = "US ABC 3.0"
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" #loads the window in the center of the screen

#Link Label 1
$LinkLabel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
$LinkLabel1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,50)
$LinkLabel1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,30)
$LinkLabel1.LinkColor = "BLUE"
$LinkLabel1.ActiveLinkColor = "RED"
$Linklabel1.AutoSize= $true
$LinkLabel1.Text = "US ABC 3.0 AOReport"
$LinkLabel1.add_Click({[system.Diagnostics.Process]::start("C:\temp\DatabaseStatusReport.htm")})
$Form.Controls.Add($LinkLabel1) 

$textLabel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TextLabel1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,90)
$TextLabel1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,10)
$Textlabel1.AutoSize= $true

$textLabel1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("TIMES NEW ROMAN",09,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)

$Form.Controls.Add($TextLabel1) 


#Show Form
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Please see output below:

[image]

I would like to get my out put as below :

I want to view the .htm or .html report output in right pane when I click the button (Lets say DatabaseReport)

[image]

Comment: hi @Matt, just updated my question with the output I am getting. Thank you.

Comment: You have to realise we have very little context for what you are trying to do, so it would make it a LOT faster if you say something like "I want X but I'm getting Y". What I can see is you have a form with a button that launches an HTML link (probably opens in default web browser if it does anything at all). What I'm not clear on is what you want to happen. Something about having the output go into the form and copied into both sides? It's not clear.

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel, Thank you,I just updated the question.please let me know if I am not clear still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if this isn't what you're looking for.  You'll just want to play with the sizes:

```
#Create Form Object
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(700,400)
$Form.Text = "US ABC 3.0"
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" #loads the window in the center of the screen

#Link Label 1
$Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20)
$Button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
$Button1.AutoSize= $true
$Button1.Text = "US ABC 3.0 AOReport"
$Form.Controls.Add($Button1) 

#Load Web Browser
$Button1.add_Click({
$webBrowser1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
$webBrowser1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60)
$webBrowser1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(650,300)
$webBrowser1.URL="C:\temp\DatabaseStatusReport.htm"
$Form.Controls.Add($webBrowser1) })


#Show Form
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

[Source](https://adminscache.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/open-web-browser-in-powershell-gui/)

Comment: Rick,thanks a lot,exactly what I wanted. I realized what I missed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Np man.  I'm pretty new to powershell, so questions like this are helping me learn too!  I started learning in Powershell Studio, so the hardest part for me was not just dragging a webbrowser into the form and being done haha

Comment: Rick,sorry for asking another question.I installed Visual Studio 2013 and deployed PowerShell tools to it.But I couldnot find wpf tools installed in PowerShell studio...can you guide me how to use PowerShell Studio.Thanks

Comment: Powershell Studio is a tool by Sapien.  It's a little costly ($389), but it's made things a lot easier for me.  https://www.sapien.com/